# I have installed tk but I got the error: import _tkinter No module named '_tkinter

Tags: python3, tkinter

First of all I am on ubuntu 19.04 and I use python 3.6.7. I try to run a program and I get the error:

`

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Pytho` may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'.
```

`

However when I type

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

I get

```
python3-tk is already the newest version
```

I do not understand why this is happening and googling has not helped me. Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How have you defined your environemnt variables TK_LIBRARY, TKPATH, and TCL_LIBRARY ?

Comment: Where do I have to define them?

Comment: You could define them in .profile, but I just have a file named "setup" in my project with the definitions (and other project specific ones), which I source before doing anything in that project.

Comment: @PadK Hello! Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you try  pip install instead? or pip3?

Comment: @Nmath I am running 20.04 LTS and am still seeing this issue.